# Plot a generalised mixed effects model with binomial errors

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, binomial-distribution, lme4-nlme

Plotting a **glm** binomial model is reasonably simple with the **predict** function. I'm having trouble creating a similar plot for a **glmer** model; predict doesn't work:

```
id    <- factor(rep(1:20, 3))
age   <- rep(sample(20:50, 20, replace=T), 3)
age   <- age + c(rep(0, 20), rep(3, 20), rep(6, 20))
score <- rbinom(60, 15, 1-age/max(age))
dfx   <- data.frame(id, age, score)

library(lme4)
glmerb  <- glmer(cbind(score, 15-score) ~ age + (1|id), dfx, family=binomial)
ndf     <- expand.grid(age=10:60) #for extensibility, usually also have factors
ndf$fit <- predict(glmerb, ndf, type="response")
*Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "mer"*
```

1. How can I produce the desired plot?
2. While I'm at it, what other plots would be useful for this kind of model for either diagnostic, presentation or glam purposes?

Comment: Of possible interest: [Using lmer for prediction](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4187/930). And it's probably worth to check what Doug Bates has to say in his draft on [lme4: Mixed-effects Modeling with R](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/) (I didn't check it, though), or maybe [LMERConvenienceFunctions](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LMERConvenienceFunctions/) on CRAN.

Comment: Unfortunately not much in his lme4 drafts. Although I will check his book. This came close http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq but there's no glmer plot only lmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `mer` class in `R`, and the `lmer` etc commands in `lme4` all produce `mer` objects, and these are not compatible with some "normal" R commands.

You can get the fits out by using `fitted` but amending your code to

```
ndf$fit <- fitted(glmerb, ndf, type="response")
```

gave me the error

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "fit", value = c(0.213527879025905,  : 
replacement has 60 rows, data has 51
```

But this worked:

```
> fit <- fitted(glmerb, ndf, type="response")
> str(fit)
num [1:60] 0.214 0.282 0.335 0.154 0.335 ...
```

Is that what you were after?

Comment: Close. What I wanted was perhaps simpler, and that is the straight fixed effects curve. Not so much individual predictions. However this is useful and satisfies Q2. Perhaps a manual command to "curve" will do the trick?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the ez package, particularly at ezPredict.

ps. if you would like to use 'to_predict' parameter, you'll need the dev version, see the instructions here: https://github.com/mike-lawrence/ez

Answer (score 2):

To plot curves of fixed effects, I typically use code like this:

```
model.coefs <- fixef(model)
curve( invlogit( cbind(1, x) %*% model.coefs ), add=TRUE )
```

Note that `invlogit` is in the [arm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arm/index.html) package.