# predict() Function for lmer Mixed Effects Models

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

**The problem:**

I have read in other [posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4202/67822) that `predict` is not available for mixed effects `lmer` {lme4} models in [R].

I tried exploring this subject with a toy dataset...

**Background:**

The dataset is adapted form [this source](http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/), and available as...

```
require(gsheet)
data <- read.csv(text = 
     gsheet2text('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QgtDcGJebyfW7TJsB8n6rAmsyAnlz1xkT3RuPFICTdk/edit?usp=sharing',
        format ='csv'))
```

These are the first rows and headers:

```
> head(data)
  Subject Auditorium Education Time  Emotion Caffeine Recall
1     Jim          A        HS    0 Negative       95 125.80
2     Jim          A        HS    0  Neutral       86 123.60
3     Jim          A        HS    0 Positive      180 204.00
4     Jim          A        HS    1 Negative      200  95.72
5     Jim          A        HS    1  Neutral       40  75.80
6     Jim          A        HS    1 Positive       30  84.56
```

We have some repeated observations (`Time`) of a continuous measurement, namely the `Recall` rate of some words, and several explanatory variables, including **random effects** (`Auditorium` where the test took place; `Subject` name); and **fixed effects**, such as `Education`, `Emotion` (the emotional connotation of the word to remember), or $\small \text{mgs.}$ of `Caffeine` ingested prior to the test.

The idea is that it's easy to remember for hyper-caffeinated wired subjects, but the ability decreases over time, perhaps due to tiredness. Words with negative connotation are more difficult to remember. Education has a predictable effect, and even the auditorium plays a role (perhaps one was more noisy, or less comfortable). Here're a couple of exploratory plots:

---

[image]

Differences in recall rate as a function of `Emotional Tone`, `Auditorium` and `Education`:

[image]

---

When fitting lines on the data cloud for the call:

`fit1 <- lmer(Recall ~ (1|Subject) + Caffeine, data = data)`

I get this plot:

[image: with the following code (notice the call for <code>predict(fit1)</code> in it):]

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Caffeine, y = Recall, colour = Subject)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = predict(fit1)),size=1) 
print(p)
```

while the following model:

`fit2 <- lmer(Recall ~ (1|Subject/Time) + Caffeine, data = data)`

incorporating `Time` and a parallel code gets a surprising plot:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Caffeine, y = Recall, colour = Subject)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = predict(fit2)),size=1) 
print(p)
```

[image]

---

**The question:**

**How does the `predict` function operate in this `lmer` model?** Evidently it's taking into consideration the `Time` variable, resulting in a much tighter fit, and the zig-zagging that is trying to display this third dimension of `Time` portrayed in the first plot.

If I call `predict(fit2)` I get `132.45609` for the first entry, which corresponds to the first point. Here is the `head` of the dataset with the output of `predict(fit2)` attached as the last column:

```
> data$predict = predict(fit2)
> head(data)
  Subject Auditorium Education Time  Emotion Caffeine Recall   predict
1     Jim          A        HS    0 Negative       95 125.80 132.45609
2     Jim          A        HS    0  Neutral       86 123.60 130.55145
3     Jim          A        HS    0 Positive      180 204.00 150.44439
4     Jim          A        HS    1 Negative      200  95.72 112.37045
5     Jim          A        HS    1  Neutral       40  75.80  78.51012
6     Jim          A        HS    1 Positive       30  84.56  76.39385
```

The coefficients for `fit2` are:

```
$`Time:Subject`
         (Intercept)  Caffeine
0:Jason     75.03040 0.2116271
0:Jim       94.96442 0.2116271
0:Ron       58.72037 0.2116271
0:Tina      70.81225 0.2116271
0:Victor    86.31101 0.2116271
1:Jason     59.85016 0.2116271
1:Jim       52.65793 0.2116271
1:Ron       57.48987 0.2116271
1:Tina      68.43393 0.2116271
1:Victor    79.18386 0.2116271
2:Jason     43.71483 0.2116271
2:Jim       42.08250 0.2116271
2:Ron       58.44521 0.2116271
2:Tina      44.73748 0.2116271
2:Victor    36.33979 0.2116271

$Subject
       (Intercept)  Caffeine
Jason     30.40435 0.2116271
Jim       79.30537 0.2116271
Ron       13.06175 0.2116271
Tina      54.12216 0.2116271
Victor   132.69770 0.2116271
```

My best bet was...

```
> coef(fit2)[[1]][2,1]
[1] 94.96442
> coef(fit2)[[2]][2,1]
[1] 79.30537
> coef(fit2)[[1]][2,2]
[1] 0.2116271
> data$Caffeine[1]
[1] 95
> coef(fit2)[[1]][2,1] + coef(fit2)[[2]][2,1] + coef(fit2)[[1]][2,2] * data$Caffeine[1]
[1] 194.3744
```

**What is the formula to get instead to `132.45609`?**

---

EDIT for rapid access... The formula to calculate the predicted value (according to the accepted answer would be based on the `ranef(fit2)` output:

```
> ranef(fit2)
$`Time:Subject`
         (Intercept)
0:Jason    13.112130
0:Jim      33.046151
0:Ron      -3.197895
0:Tina      8.893985
0:Victor   24.392738
1:Jason    -2.068105
1:Jim      -9.260334
1:Ron      -4.428399
1:Tina      6.515667
1:Victor   17.265589
2:Jason   -18.203436
2:Jim     -19.835771
2:Ron      -3.473053
2:Tina    -17.180791
2:Victor  -25.578477

$Subject
       (Intercept)
Jason   -31.513915
Jim      17.387103
Ron     -48.856516
Tina     -7.796104
Victor   70.779432
```

... for the first entry point:

```
> summary(fit2)$coef[1]
[1] 61.91827             # Overall intercept for Fixed Effects 
> ranef(fit2)[[1]][2,]   
[1] 33.04615             # Time:Subject random intercept for Jim
> ranef(fit2)[[2]][2,]
[1] 17.3871              # Subject random intercept for Jim
> summary(fit2)$coef[2]
[1] 0.2116271            # Fixed effect slope
> data$Caffeine[1]
[1] 95                   # Value of caffeine

summary(fit2)$coef[1] + ranef(fit2)[[1]][2,] + ranef(fit2)[[2]][2,] + 
                    summary(fit2)$coef[2] * data$Caffeine[1]
[1] 132.4561
```

The code for this post is [here](https://github.com/RInterested/REGRESSION/blob/master/LMER%20PLOTTING%20PREDICT).

Comment: Note that there has been a `predict` function in this package since Version 1.0-0, released 2013-08-01. See the [package news page in CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/news.html). If there hadn't been, you wouldn't have been able to get any results with `predict`. Don't forget that you can see the R code with lme4:::predict.merMod at the R command prompt, and inspect the source for any underlying compiled functions in the source package for `lme4`.

Comment: Thanks, I see there is the functionality with either the random effects disregarded or included. Do you know where I can find how it is calculated? If I type `?predict` on the [r] console, I get the basic predict for {stats}...

Comment: @EdM ... yes, this is new to me... Thank you. I hadn't called `predict.merMod`, though... As you can see on the OP, I called simply `predict`...

Comment: Load the `lme4` package, then type lme4:::predict.merMod to see the package-specific version. The output from `lmer` is stored in an object of class `merMod`.

Comment: @EdM So you're saying that when I use `predict` and have `lme4` loaded in the Environment, it automatically uses the {lme4} `predict.merMod`?

Comment: One of the beauties of R is that a function like `predict` knows what to do depending on the class of the object that it is called to act upon. You were calling `predict.merMod`, you just didn't know it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29548/discussion-between-antoni-parellada-and-edm).

Comment: Which package did you use to create that first plot? It's awesome!

Comment: @JLC Believe it or not, it took me a while to find it... Here is all the code with the packages needed: https://github.com/RInterested/REGRESSION/blob/master/LMER%20PLOTTING%20PREDICT

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's easy to get confused by the presentation of coefficients when you call `coef(fit2)`. Look at the summary of fit2:

> ```
> > summary(fit2)
> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
> Formula: Recall ~ (1 | Subject/Time) + Caffeine
>    Data: data
> ```

```
REML criterion at convergence: 444.5

Scaled residuals: 
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.88657 -0.46382 -0.06054  0.31430  2.16244 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Time:Subject (Intercept)  558.4   23.63   
 Subject      (Intercept) 2458.0   49.58   
 Residual                  675.0   25.98   
Number of obs: 45, groups:  Time:Subject, 15; Subject, 5

Fixed effects:
Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 61.91827   25.04930   2.472
Caffeine     0.21163    0.07439   2.845

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
 (Intr)
Caffeine -0.365
```

There is an overall intercept of 61.92 for the model, with a caffeine coefficient of 0.212. So for caffeine = 95 you predict an average 82.06 recall.

Instead of using `coef`, use `ranef` to get the difference of each random-effect intercept from the mean intercept at the next higher level of nesting:

> ```
> > ranef(fit2)
> $`Time:Subject`
>          (Intercept)
> 0:Jason    13.112130
> 0:Jim      33.046151
> 0:Ron      -3.197895
> 0:Tina      8.893985
> 0:Victor   24.392738
> 1:Jason    -2.068105
> 1:Jim      -9.260334
> 1:Ron      -4.428399
> 1:Tina      6.515667
> 1:Victor   17.265589
> 2:Jason   -18.203436
> 2:Jim     -19.835771
> 2:Ron      -3.473053
> 2:Tina    -17.180791
> 2:Victor  -25.578477
> ```

```
$Subject
       (Intercept)
Jason   -31.513915
Jim      17.387103
Ron     -48.856516
Tina     -7.796104
Victor   70.779432
```

The values for Jim at Time=0 will differ from that average value of 82.06 by the sum of both his `Subject` *and* his `Time:Subject` coefficients:

$$82.06+17.39+33.04=132.49$$

which I think is within rounding error of 132.46.

The intercept values returned by `coef` seem to represent the overall intercept plus the `Subject` or `Time:Subject` specific differences, so it's harder to work with those; if you tried to do the above calculation with the `coef` values you would be double-counting the overall intercept.

Comment: Thank you! This was outstanding! I don't  think there's any point in leaving it open... This is _the_ answer, isn't it?

Comment: I got the hint about `ranef` from examining R code in `lme4`. I clarified the presentation in a couple of places.

Comment: (+1) Note: time random effects nested within person somehow looks weird.

Comment: @MichaelM : Yes, the data as presented seem to be a crossed (Time x Subject) rather than a nested design, but this is the way the OP raised the  question of how to interpret `lme4` output. Also, the data presented seemed to be for illustration rather than being a real study to be analyzed.