# Centering predictors in linear mixed effects and explaining three-way interactions with continuous variables

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, interpretation, centering

I am working on a Linear Mixed Effects model. All four predictors are continuous variables.
Full model:
`fm15 = lmer (duration  ~ A*B*C+D+ ( 1 | subjects ) + ( 1 |words), data=data, REML= FALSE)`

I have two questions: a) Should I center the predictors? If so, which way should I use to center it? Why are the results different using different centering methods?

In my case the continuous variables do not contain a significant value of 0. I tried to center the predictors by subtracting the mean and subtracting the min. However, after reducing the model by removing non-significant terms, I got two outputs:

**Subtracting the mean:**

`fm16 = lmer (duration  ~ A+B+C+D+AC+ ( 1 | subjects ) + ( 1 |words), data=data, REML= FALSE)`

**Output:**

[image]

**Subtracting the min:**

`fm16 = lmer (duration  ~ A+B+C+D+AB+BC+ABC ( 1 | subjects ) + ( 1 |words), data=data, REML= FALSE)`

**Output:**

[image]

The terms in red are significant.

My second question is how to interpret the output? Such as output containing two-way and three-way interactions?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mean centering interaction terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417029/mean-centering-interaction-terms) Centering a predictor involved in an interaction changes the coefficients for the lower-level coefficients of the predictors _with which it interacts_. The underlying model is the same, however. It's typically not helpful to interpret low-level coefficients of predictors involved in interactions without specifying particular values for other predictors.

Comment: @EdM Thank you very much! It answers my first question! Do you have any suggestions for my second question, please?

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/489864/28500) and its related links about interpreting interaction coefficients up to 3-way. There are other similar Q&A on this site. An interaction coefficient is an _extra difference_ when _all_ of the corresponding interacting predictors are non-zero. Try writing out the full equation in terms of coefficients for predictors and their interactions, recognizing that an "interaction" is just a product of predictor values. Principles are the same for all types of linear modeling, including mixed models and generalized linear models.