# Random effect coefficient: actual coefficient or deviation from main fixed effect?

Tags: mixed-model, matlab, random-effects-model, intercept

This is a very simple question, but I'm starting to doubt myself:

I have a mixed model which I estimate in Matlab with fitglm

```
mdl = fitglme(data, 'DV ~ 1 + IV + (1+IV|subject)')
```

The following piece of code extracts the random effects coefficients (i.e. the individual b0 and b1's)

```
[B,BNames,stats]= randomEffects(mdl)
```

Now I'm wondering: Are those resulting coefficients deviations from the main fixed effect coefficient? So, say to interpret an individual random intercept, I would need to take the main intercept (fixed) and add the random intercept to it? And the same with the random slope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no generally correct answer to this, as it depends on the specific software. Even within the same mixed-modeling software, whether you get deviations from the fixed effect or predictions including the fixed effect can depend on just how you interrogate the model; see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/174227/28500) for an example.

The best way to tell (if the manual page isn't clear) is to examine the distributions of the values of the random effects. If they center around 0 (for a corresponding non-zero fixed-effect value) then they are deviations from the fixed-effect estimates.